# Universal Windows App открытие произвольного файла

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Коллеги, пытаюсь создать свое первое UWP приложение. Необходимо открыть произвольный файл, но не представляю как это сделать. Получаю ошибку доступа. Через FileOpenPicker, конечно, все норм, но мне нужно именно открыть произвольный файл, чтобы иметь возможность открыть приложение с аргументами запуска (указав имя файла).

Сразу отвечу на вопрос о конечной цели, вдруг кто-нибудь предложит иное решение:

Нужна ассоциация файлов определенного типа с приложением.

Comment: А права на доступ к ФС в манифесте объявлены?

Comment: @Андрей, я не нашел там такого права.... есть отдельные права на Картинки, документы.... и все

Comment: Тут смотрели? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation